# paypal_ipn trouble inserting into sql-server database

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, paypal-ipn

Good evening, I have been playing with Paypal IPN and everything seams to be OK however it will not insert into my database.

I am using sql server/mssql2008.

I have tested the Database connections to see if it errors out and I don't get any logs for it. any help here would be greatly appreciated.

-Chris

```
define("DEBUG", 1);
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));


$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) 
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;

} else {

        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);


            list($headers, $res) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $res, 2);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}


if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }

    if ($payment_status == "Completed")
    { 

        if(DEBUG == true) 
        {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "COMPLETED PAYMENT STATUS");
        }


$database_user = "dbuser";
$database_pass = "dbpass";
$database_dbo4 = "datebase";

$conn4=odbc_connect($database_dbo4,$database_user,$database_pass);
$account = "testaccountid";
$amounttotal = 5; 


$sql = "insert into donation (accountid, amount) VALUES ($account, $amounttotal)";


$result = odbc_exec($conn4, $sql);





    } 
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I set to live it comes up with VERIFIED and writes it to the log file. I need it to come up as completed as that is where my database entry is. 

any ideas on how to make this continue would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran the follow code on the very top of my listener

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I then manually ran the listener in firefox and it errors at Database settings, I had an issue with the username... Doh.

I then found it still won't insert but with some playing around I found this in my code

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }

// IF USING EBAY AND A WEBSITE TO SELL GOODS THEN YOU NEED TO ENSURE THE PAYMENT STATUS IS COMPLETED AND DETERMINE WHICH CHANNEL SENT THE REQUEST
// USE CUSTOM FIELD TO DETERMINE WHAT SENT THE PAYMENT  
//$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
//  $custid =  $_POST["custom"];
//  $txn_type = $_POST["txn_type"];
//  $item_name = $_POST['item_name1'];
```

All I did was remove the // from

```
//$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
```

now everything is working and I can make my own checks!

Hope this answer helps other people.

Thanks